# Is there a dictionary guidebook?

Tags: dictionaries

I know books of episodes of OED, and short guides for a few dictionaries, but I don't know a dictionary guidebook. 
The book has more than 200 pages, and a long list of viewpoints to evaluate dictionary, and fascinating essays about reading dictionaries, and finally a score table comparing more than 20 dictionaries. In Japanese language (my mother tongue) there is such a book, and I want to know English equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: Here is an online list: http://www.refseek.com/directory/dictionaries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a valuable information source, but I have never seen such a thing.
It would be useful for learners to know what dictionaries are useful for beginners, advanced students and what are the standard dictionaries.
But there are several difficulties. Beginners need bilingual dictionaries and those dictionaries are different from country to country.
As to monolingual dictionaries I think learners should get information about OALD  and other outstanding dictionaries.
A lot of information would be necessary about standard dictionaries of Oxford, Longman, Harrap, Collins, etc and about American dictionaries, which don't give the pronunciation in IPA signs. Besides, lexicology is a field which is in constant move.

Longman, Dictionary of Contemporary English has so many innovative features that the difference to dictionaries of the sixties is overwhelming.

And, of course, there should be information about dictionaries on the internet, a field that is rapidly changing.

And other new electronic developments in this field as electronic dictionaries and applications fot smart phones.

A similar guide would be necessary for grammars, especially because a lot of learners don't know what a grammar is good for. They learn grammar from exercise books, from the internet or online forums.

I think an online portal for such information would be necessary and a staff of specialists who keep such a portal up-to-date.